# vuejs - работа с компонентами без npm

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Изучаю сейчас vuejs. В уроках для разворачивания простого приложения со структурой, представленной ниже, понадобилось поставить node.js, загрузить кучу зависимостей на 60+мб, запускать сервер вручную и т.п. Как я понимаю, всё это на базе webpack.

```
css
src
--components
--App.vue
--main.js
index.html
```

И тут сразу получается, что чтобы что-то сложнее формы-кнопки сделать, нужно всё это городить. Честно - расстроился. Или всё это только для разработки нужно, а потом можно всё это как-то "скомпилировать" в рабочее приложение без лишнего? Можно ли обойтись без всей этой махины, оставив возможности модульной разработки? Как тут быть? По факту, получается, такое на обычный хостинг даже и не поставишь - нужен VPS и node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скомпилировать можно, конечно.

Например, в [webpack-шаблоне](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) для vue встроена возможность компиляции (файл [`build/build.js`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/build.js)), при запуске которого (`node build/build.js`) создаётся папка `/dist`, в которой будет файл `index.html` и все другие ресурсы (минифицированный код, файлы стилей, картинки и т.д.).

Эту папку при желании можно перенести на сервер, без необходимости устанавливать node или что-нибудь ещё.

[Связанная статья на ru.vuejs.org](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html)

Comment: аллилуйя!) Вы мне прямо вмиг настроение подняли очень сильно))) Спасибо) Буду пробовать-разбираться)

Answer (score 0):

Использовать http загрузчик vue модулей:
https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/741770)